# Script to check the change of crontab using diff

Tags: linux, cron

I need a script which needs to look in a way that take copy of the current crontab in a file then every day a cron tab copy needs to be taken and it needs to compare using "`diff`" command if it is not matching it needs to send alert mail.Can any one please help me on this?

Currently I'm using the below script But  issue with this script is it sends alerts even if the Changes made in the crontab are correct.But I want to compare the contents using the diff command.So this script not suits for my requirement

```
#!/bin/sh
    export smtp=smtprelay.intra.coriant.com:25
    CROND=/home/ssx00001
    ALERT=redmine@coriant.com
    checkf=last.crontab.check
    if [ -f $checkf ]
    then
    find $CROND -type f -newer $checkf | while read tabfile
    do
        echo "Crontab file for Redmine has changed" | mail -s "Crontab changed" $ALERT
    done
    fi
    touch $CHECKF
```

Comment: @fedoqui:Got the above script from the above question but my requirement is different....it needs to use the diff command...

Comment: That's only checking whether the timestamp on the file changed, not if the file itself actually changed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh
export smtp=smtprelay.intra.coriant.com:25
ALERT=redmine@coriant.com
crontab -l > /home/ssx00001/y.txt
cat y.txt
diff /home/ssx00001/x.txt  /home/ssx00001/y.txt > /home/ssx00001/z.txt
ab=`cat z.txt | wc -l`
echo $ab
if [[ $ab != 0 ]]; then
echo "Crontab for Redmine has changed" | mail  -s "Crontab modified" $ALERT
fi
```

(`/home/ssx00001` is the path in which files stored ?)
Also create a file in /home/ssx00001 as x.txt which contains data of current cronjobs

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that the `diff` command requires two files to compare.  You cannot check for changes in a file without saving an old version of the file to check against.  The `crontab` command does not do this.

Your best bet is to write a wrapper around the `crontab` command which saves a copy of the original crontab file, runs `crontab` to edit and install the new file, and then runs `diff` with the file you saved.

Comment: thanks hymie, any sample code segment for this? so that it will help me a lot